# pcks5 padding

Tags: security

I have  text with 20 octets and 32 octets. So the first one is a complete 16 bytes block and 32 octets is 26 bytes. When I encrypt the file used aes-cbc mode the padding will not be done for the first one, but the padding will be done for the 2nd one. Which is the number of zeros that should be put to make it 32. i.e., the 32th byte will be 5 and the rest of them are zeros. When I encrypted the file with the key.. I have some cipher text. 
My question is since from 27-31 are zeros, when the text is encrypted should the algorithm give me the same cipher text between 27-31. Or how will I know that the zeros are added and 5 is the 32nd byte in the text since the value is encrypted.

Correct me if i am wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) - which defines the PKCS#5 padding - the padding contains in each byte the length of the padding (in bytes). Therefore if you read the last byte of the last decrypted block you received, you will find the information how many padding bytes you can discard.